# checking return value of upper_bound in STL sorted vector

Tags: c++, stl

I have following program

```
int main()
{
    int myints[] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7};
    vector<int> v(myints,myints+7);
    vector<int>::iterator low,up;

    sort (v.begin(), v.end());

    low=lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 5);          ^
    up= upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20);                   ^

    cout << "lower_bound at position " << int(low- v.begin()) << endl;
    cout << "upper_bound at position " << int(up - v.begin()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have following output on above

> lower_bound at position 5 upper_bound at position 7 Press any key to
>   continue . . .

My question is how to check upper bound return value in above case there is no value greather than 20?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need only to check if the iterator of the upper bound is equal to v.end():

```
if (up == v.end())
    // there is no value greater than your upper bound
```

For more informations about upper_bound see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/

Answer (score 1):

```
auto up = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 20);

cout<<*up<<endl; //dereference iterator and you will get a value
```

To check if iterator is valid compare it with end() iterator:

```
if (up == v.end()) {
    //no upper bound
}
```